# Circular reference and constructors

Tags: f#, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I'm trying to build an Attribute that validates a certain instance of a type.

In order to do this I have to cast the `ObjectInstance` to that type.

And I need to set the attribute on the member of that type.

So we need to resort to the `and` keyword for the circular definition.

However in the following case I get the error that

> A custom attribute must invoke an object constructor

On the line marked below.

```
namespace Test

open System
open System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)>]
type MyAttribute() =
    class
    inherit ValidationAttribute ()

    override this.IsValid (value: Object, validationContext: ValidationContext) =
        match validationContext.ObjectInstance with
        | :? MyClass as item ->
            // TODO more validation
            ValidationResult.Success
        | _ ->
            new ValidationResult("No no no")
    end
and MyClass(someValue) =
    [<Required>]
    [<Range(1, 7)>]
  //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    [<MyAttribute>]
  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    member this.SomeValue : int = someValue
```

I tried manually invoking the constructor, such as:

```
[<MyAttribute()>]
// or
[<new MyAttribute()>]
```

But none of them are accepted by the system.

Can an F# guru help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to first describe your types in a signature files.

Since the attribute is specified in the signature file, you don't need to add it again in the implementation file:

**Foo.fsi:**

```
namespace Foo

open System

[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>]
type MyAttribute =
    inherit System.Attribute

    new : unit -> MyAttribute

    member Foo : unit -> MyClass

and MyClass =
    new : someValue : int -> MyClass

    [<MyAttribute()>]
    member SomeValue : int
```

**Foo.fs:**

```
namespace Foo

open System

[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>]
type MyAttribute() =
    inherit Attribute()

    member this.Foo () =
        new MyClass(1)

and MyClass(someValue) =
    // [<MyAttribute()>] -> specified in the fsi, still appears in compiled code
    member this.SomeValue : int = someValue
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx for reference

Answer (score 7):

Interesting one. It seems that the type inference is really not getting that right. The correct syntax to use here is `[<MyAttribute()>]`, but despite you using the `and` keyword, the `MyAttribute` class is not yet known.

Here is a workaround: First check that the object to validate is really of the right type, then use reflection to invoke a validation method:

```
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)>]
type MyAttribute() =
    inherit ValidationAttribute ()

    override this.IsValid (value: Object, validationContext: ValidationContext) =
        let t = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
        if t.FullName = "Test.MyClass" then
            let p = t.GetMethod("IsValid")
            if p.Invoke(validationContext.ObjectInstance, [| |]) |> unbox<bool> then
                ValidationResult.Success
            else
                ValidationResult("failed")
        else
            new ValidationResult("No no no")

type MyClass(someValue: int) =
    [<Required>]
    [<Range(1, 7)>]
    [<MyAttribute()>]
    member this.SomeValue = someValue

    member this.IsValid() = someValue <= 7
```

**Edit**: to make that slightly cleaner, you could add an interface, that you use in your validation attribute, and later implement in your class.

```
type IIsValid =
    abstract member IsValid: unit -> bool
```

Your IsValid method then becomes

```
    override this.IsValid (value: Object, validationContext: ValidationContext) =

        match validationContext.ObjectInstance with
        | :? IIsValid as i -> 
            if i.IsValid() then
                ValidationResult.Success
            else
                ValidationResult("failed")
        | _ ->
            ValidationResult("No no no")
```

in your class, this looks like:

```
type MyClass(someValue: int) =
    [<Required>]
    [<Range(1, 7)>]
    [<MyAttribute()>]
    member this.SomeValue = someValue

    interface IIsValid with
        member this.IsValid() = someValue <= 7
```

Comment: That is a possible solution, but it is quite (understatement) dirty. Thank you!

Comment: Not claiming this is the cleanest solution :-) Let me add another one.

Comment: I like your new workaround better. I leave it open a little longer, maybe somebody comes with a real solution. If not, the points are yours.

I also filed a bug on the FSharp project on GitHub: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/565

Comment: I like this idea - you'll only have a single attribute type + a generally useful interface to implement, instead of creating loads of single-use attribute types. ComponentModel is a mess.

Comment: Don Syme just confirmed that this is in fact a compiler bug, see @Snake's report on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/565)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you can do to get rid of mutual recursion is to break up `MyClass` definition into two and use type augmentation to add the members you want to mark with the attribute.

```
type MyClass(someValue: int) =
    member internal this.InternalSomeValue = someValue

type MyAttribute() = 
    inherit ValidationAttribute()
    (* you can refer to MyClass here *)

type MyClass with
    [<MyAttribute()>]
    member this.SomeValue = this.InternalSomeValue
```

That's closer to what you're asking for, but I like the interface idea better.